# Microsoft Azure B2C - Get Profile Information

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin.forms, azure-ad-b2c, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am moments from giving up entirely on this workflow.

I set up an Azure account with a REST API, a few other things, and then a b2c AD. After hours and hours of hating my life, I finally have it (somewhat) working to use this AD to sign in, and to be required to access the REST API.

The problem I am now having is that I have tried every single variation of anything I can find only about how to get the profile information of that person who is logged in, and I am getting absolutely nothing.

Even the example files after login don't properly work - it is meant to redirect you to a page that says welcome (username) but the username does not return in my result to

```
 result = await App.AuthenticationClient
                    .AcquireTokenInteractive(B2CConstants.Scopes)
                    .WithPrompt(Microsoft.Identity.Client.Prompt.SelectAccount)
                    .WithParentActivityOrWindow(App.UIParent)
                    .ExecuteAsync();
```

None of this is the least bit intuitive. I have read docs but somehow every time I google it I end up on a different page of Microsoft docs with different information.

I do not know what I need to pass to scopes... I do not know how to property get an auth token, as every time I try and use graphs I get an error about an empty or invalid auth token (even after logging in).

Even though I logged in with google successfully, the result above gives me a NULL access token, null tenant id, null scopes, null username under account... the ONLY thing that is correct is the unique ID lines up with the ID I see on the AD users page.

EDIT: the AccessToken is not null actually, I get info there... but every call I try to make that I think should use it is failing.

Ie, if I try to call this to get my info after signing in:

```
InteractiveAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new InteractiveAuthenticationProvider(App.AuthenticationClient, B2CConstants.Scopes);
                GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);
                var users = await graphClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();
```

Note the App.AuthenticationClient is what I used to login above - I have also tried this with

```
            //.Create(B2CConstants.ClientId)
            //.Build();
```

I get this (only partial error so I don't pass out IDs)

```
Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: 'Code: InvalidAuthenticationToken
Message: Access token validation failure.
Inner error:
    AdditionalData:
    date: 2020-10-26T21:45:25
```

Comment: If you want to call Microsoft graph, you need to get Azure AD access token. According to your code, it seems that you get b2c token to call Microsoft Graph.  Regarding how to call Microsoft graph in B2C tenant, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/microsoft-graph-get-started?tabs=app-reg-ga

Answer (score 0):

*I suggest that you mostly refer Microsoft Docs for any information.*

Consider below code to get users details from B2C **(This is Android Xamarin Forms page .cs code)**:

```
async void OnSignInSignOut(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AuthenticationResult authResult = null;
            IEnumerable<IAccount> accounts = await App.PCA.GetAccountsAsync();
            try
            {
                if (btnSignInSignOut.Text == "Sign in")
                {
                    try
                    {
                        IAccount firstAccount = accounts.FirstOrDefault();
                        authResult = await App.PCA.AcquireTokenSilent(App.Scopes, firstAccount)
                                              .ExecuteAsync();
                    }
                    catch (MsalUiRequiredException ex)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            authResult = await App.PCA.AcquireTokenInteractive(App.Scopes)
                                                      .WithParentActivityOrWindow(App.ParentWindow)
                                                      .ExecuteAsync();
                        }
                        catch(Exception ex2)
                        {
                            await DisplayAlert("Acquire token interactive failed. See exception message for details: ", ex2.Message, "Dismiss");
                        }
                    }

                    if (authResult != null)
                    {
                        var content = await GetHttpContentWithTokenAsync(authResult.AccessToken);
                        UpdateUserContent(content);
                        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => { btnSignInSignOut.Text = "Sign out"; });
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    while (accounts.Any())
                    {
                        await App.PCA.RemoveAsync(accounts.FirstOrDefault());
                        accounts = await App.PCA.GetAccountsAsync();
                    }

                    slUser.IsVisible = false;
                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => { btnSignInSignOut.Text = "Sign in"; });
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Authentication failed. See exception message for details: ", ex.Message, "Dismiss");
            }
        }
```

For complete and step by step samples on B2C integration, you can visit below links:

- [Integrate Microsoft identity and the Microsoft Graph into a Xamarin forms app using MSAL](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-xamarin-native-v2/tree/master/1-Basic)
- [Integrate Azure AD B2C into a Xamarin forms app using MSAL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native/integrate-azure-ad-b2c-xamarin-forms/)

Comment: So, as always, the reason I am posting and asking for help is I have followed this doc and its not giving me the users information.

Comment: The method you are using is different that this one. Can you clone this solution and simply setup as per the instructions and test it out? It should work. I have used this solution in the past.

Comment: I showed only one attempt - I have tried many things. The only thing I have working (somehwat) is just doing an HTTP Request to url/.auth/me with my access token - however the problem here is that when i make a new account in the app, and then run the request i get no results - until i go to that URL in my browser on my laptop manually, which gives results, then the app suddenyl starts working too

Comment: Did you try cloning this and setting it up for you?